# Releasing/close network ports?

Tags: java, android, networking, libgdx, port

I am fiddling around with sockets in `LibGDX`. But each time i want to run my program I have to change the `PORT` in the code, obviously because this port is taken by the previous run. Can I perhaps close the port when the program shuts down or maybe connect through that port again? Otherwise is there anything I can do to release that specific port without rebooting?

I am running a separate thread that creates the socket server and loops for receiving. Below this thread is a ClickListener that sends message to the server, currently all inside the same app. How would i set this up so i can reuse the socket or close it when the program closes in any way?

```
            new Thread(new Runnable(){    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ServerSocketHints serverSocketHint = new ServerSocketHints();
                serverSocketHint.acceptTimeout = 0;
                ServerSocket serverSocket = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(Protocol.TCP, 9024, serverSocketHint);

                while(true){
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(null);

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 

                    try {
                        labelMessage.setText(buffer.readLine());    
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override 
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){

                String textToSend = new String();
                if(textMessage.getText().length() == 0)
                    textToSend = "Empty message\n";
                else
                    textToSend = textMessage.getText() + ("\n");

                SocketHints socketHints = new SocketHints();
                socketHints.connectTimeout = 4000;

                Socket socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, textIPAddress.getText(), 9024, socketHints);
                try {
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(textToSend.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Call `setReuseAddress(true)` before you bind the socket.

But you should certainly close all sockets before you exit.